# WebBrowser does not redirect

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser

I am wondering why my webbrowser doesn't redirect to my html page.

I have a linkbutton on my xaml page with a tap event and i'm creating my object webbrowser when i load first the page.

This is the code I am using :

```
 private void web_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        wbbrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/index.html", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

This is the Xaml i am using :

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="about me">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="483" >
                <Rectangle Height="186" Width="150"  Margin="-250,0,9,10" >
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Img/id.jpg"></ImageBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Text ="Name" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="age" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="nationality" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="adress" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="phone" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="email" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="others" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                <HyperlinkButton Name="web" Content="web version"  Margin="12,-6,12,10" Tap="web_Tap"></HyperlinkButton>

            </StackPanel>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

So I am actually not declaring the Phone:WebBrowser.
I just create my object at the main page loaded .

Comment: I also tried this wbbrowser.navigatetostring() method.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside this event to see if it's get called?

Comment: Yes the nethod navigating is called

Comment: Have you tried another web site cause I tested the Code and it worked :)

Comment: Have you tried browsing to the web page via Internet Explorer on the phone, rather than witin your application. Does the web page appear?

Comment: even with something like google.com it doesnt appear..

Comment: Shouldn't I determinate the height of the webbrowser etc ? in the xaml for example ?

Comment: Please provide your XAML in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using the **HyperlinkButton** the wrong way. You need to add a `TargetName="NAME_OF_TARGET"` for it to navigate. Second, use the `NavigateUri` property to navigate to a page instead of handling the tap.

This has been described in the [MSDN documentation article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).